# How do you refer to the fictional author of a poem?

Tags: nouns, personal-pronouns

If a poem is written in the first person, how do you refer to the first person character in the poem?

e.g.

> Underneath the fallen blossom
>   In my bosom,
>   Is a letter I have hid.
>   It was brought to me this morning by a rider from
>   Duke.

Answer (score 8):

The person could be describes as the **narrator** or, in some contexts, the **persona**.

Answer (score 2):

#### *[soliloquist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soliloquist)*

> A person who soliloquizes.
>
> ---
>
> *[soliloquize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/soliloquize)*
>
> > *v.intr.*  to utter a soliloquy; talk to oneself.
> >     *v.tr.*  to utter in a soliloquy; say to oneself.
> >     [1750–60]
> >
> > ---
> >
> > *[soliloquy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/soliloquy)*
> >
> > > 1. a) A dramatic or literary form of discourse in which a character talks to himself or herself or reveals his or her thoughts without addressing a listener.
> > >           b) A specific speech or piece of writing in this form of discourse.
> > > 2. The act of speaking to oneself.

Comment: It's a good word to know, but just because something is presented in the first-person, it doesn't mean it's a soliloquy. Only if the speaker and the addressee are one and the same person do we have soliloquy. E.g. _To be, or not to be_.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, she would be the **[protagonist](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/protagonist?view=uk)**

> the leading character or one of the major characters in a play, film, novel, etc.: